# static NSStrings in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I frequently see a code snippet like this in class instance methods:

```
static NSString *myString = @"This is a string.";
```

I can't seem to figure out why this works.  Is this simply the objc equivalent of a #define that's limited to the method's scope?  I (think) I understand the static nature of the variable, but more specifically about NSStrings, why isn't it being alloc'd, init'd?

Thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just stumbled upon the very same `static NSString` declaration. I wondered how exactly this static magic works, so I read up a bit. I'm only gonna address the static part of your question.

According to [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language) every variable in C has two basic attributes: **type** (e.g. float) and **storage class** (auto, register, static, extern, typedef).

The **static** storage class has two different effects depending on whether it's used:

- inside of a block of code (e.g. inside of a function),
- outside of all blocks (at the same level as a function).

A variable **inside a block** that doesn't have it's storage class declared is by default considered to be auto (i.e. it's local). It will get deleted as soon as the block exits. When you declare an automatic variable to be static it will keep it's value upon exit. That value will still be there when the block of code gets invoked again.

Global variables (declared at the same level as a function) are always static. Explicitly declaring a global variable (or a function) to be **static** limits its scope to just the single source code file. It won't be accessible from and it won't conflict with other source files. This is called **internal linkage**.

If you'd like to find out more then read up on [internal and external linkage in C](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter4/linkage.html).

Answer (score 9):

I think the question has two unrelated parts.

One is why isn't it being alloc'ed and init'ed. The answer is that when you write a Objective-C string literal of the `@"foo"` form, the Objective-C compiler will create an `NSString` instance for you.

The other question is what the `static` modifier does. It does the same that it does in a C function, ensuring that the `myString` variable is the same each time the method is used (even between different object instances).

A `#define` macro is something quite different: It's "programmatic cut and paste" of source code, executed before the code arrives at the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

For the part of `NSString alloc, init`:

I think first, it can be thought as a convenience, but it is not equally the same for `[[NSString alloc] init]`.

I found a useful link here. You can take a look at that
[NSString and shortcuts](http://lists.apple.com/archives/objc-language/2004/Feb/msg00034.html)

For the part of `static` and `#define`:

`static` instance in the class means you can access using any instance of the class. You can change the value of static. For the function, it means variable's value is preserved between function calls

`#define` is you put a macro constant to avoid magic number and string and define function macros. `#define MAX_NUMBER 100`. then you can use `int a[MAX_MUMBER]`. When the code is compiled, it will be copied and pasted to `int a[100]`

Comment: It wasn't me, but I do agree -- your answer is simply incomprehensible. See my answer, it breaks apart the original poster's question into three different topics (how `@"text"` literals are treated, what the `static` keyword does, and how this differs from a `#define`) and gives clear answers that hopefully people can learn something from.

Comment: Ah, ok. I lacked the part of static. Because, at the first time, I only know about NSString alloc, init so I only answer for that part. I will edit my answer

Comment: `static`, in this context, doesn't have anything to do with classes.

Comment: I don't get it, static instance mean the same for instances in class, right?

Comment: The `static` keyword can mean lots of different things depending on the context. In this context we are talking about a variable declared `static` within a function, which simply means its value is preserved between calls to the function. The fact that the function also happens to be a method is irrelevant.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks, I see the word inside the method of the question

Answer (score 2):

You don't see a call to `alloc`/`init` because the `@"..."` construct creates a *constant* string in memory (via the compiler).

In this context, `static` means that the variable cannot be accessed out of the file in which it is defined.

Answer (score 1):

It's a special case init case for `NSString` which simply points the `NSString` pointer to an instance allocated and inited at startup (or maybe lazily, I'm not sure.)  There is one one of these `NSString` instances created in this fashion for each unique `@""` you use in your program.

Also I think this is true even if you don't use the static keyword.  Furthermore I think all other `NSStrings` initialized with this string will point to the same instance (not a problem because they are immutable.)

It's not the same as a `#define`, because you actually have an `NSString` variable by creating the string with the `= @"whatever"` initialization. It seems more equivalent to c's `const char* somestr = "blah blah blah"`.